# Airport Change from La Guardia TO JFK

Tags: airports

Traveling from Toronto to Accra, Ghana. The Itinerary states :
Toronto - New York-LGA: Air Canada
(Airport Change) 
New York-JFK - Lisbon: Tap Air Portugal
Lisbon - Accra: Tap Air Portugal
Will I be responsible for transferring my baggage from LGA to JFK?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117557/2-hour-layover-between-flights-laguardia-to-jfk and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89000/would-3-hours-be-an-ok-transfer-time-from-lga-to-jfk-for-international-flight

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to collect the baggage and take the baggage with you and recheck the baggage.

There is bus services from LGA to JFK.

Comment: Also plan for quite some time to deplane, reclaim your luggage, exit the airport, wait for the bus, the bus transfer (especially at peak times), re-checking-in (before the check-in deadline), going through security, and getting to your gate (before the boarding deadline).